# double backslash and single backslash result in same string on the command line

Tags: bash

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
char *str;
str = argv[1]; 
printf("%s", str);
return 0; }
```

When program is executed using these two strings:

```
$./program "\abc"
$./program "\\abc"
```

Both run stores same string in `str` variable, as `str = \\abc`.

How to get four backslashes when run with `\\abc` or single backslash when run with `\abc` ?

Comment: Which terminal do you use to execute your program?

Comment: I am using default ubuntu terminal

Comment: This has nothing to do with C and everything to do with how you run your program (i.e. your shell), which apparently is bash.

Comment: I [can't reproduce the problem](https://tio.run/##NYvLCsIwFET3@YohYF@0PtbBL1EXt5eadNG03MQiqN8eU8TFDHOYmZ6CS2lgN6McfcREo6@2QGK5BTsSNE2GtcZL/TBEMSobzttqvZxuBmqR/LpXehd0i1zWRskQH@JxNPiUeMMyo3tmoZuxyGyFJhQF9oc/6Cv1rFP6Ag). I get `\abc` as output, not `\\vabc`.

Comment: You don't need a C program to expose the `argv` array. Try something like `printf '>>%s<<\n' "$@"` at your shell prompt (or put it in a script file with a suitable shebang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will never get four backslashes from `\\`, but if you want to pass a string literally, use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

For example:

```
./program '\abc'   # passes a four-character string: \ a b c
./program '\\abc'  # passes a five-character string: \ \ a b c
```

Comment: is there any way to detect if single backslash or double backslash passed in the string (between double quotes).

Comment: @Jaat What are you talking about?

Comment: is there any way to retain the literal value of single backslash while using double quotes to pass the string?

Comment: @Jaat Use a shell that is not bash (and not compatible with any other unix shell)? Why do you want to redefine how the shell works?

Comment: i am trying to make a program that dumps hex of a string. But the problem is that "\\n" resulted into  '0a' instead of '5c6e'.

Comment: @Jaat That has nothing to do with what you posted here. The shell won't just combine `\n` into a single newline character (unless you use `$'...'`, which I'm pretty sure doesn't happen by accident).

Comment: @Jaat By the way, you don't need a C program for that. You can play around with `perl -e 'printf "%*vx\n", " ", $ARGV[0]' 'A\nB'` to see the bytes that the shell passes to programs (output should be `41 5c 6e 42`). If you see anything unexpected here, it's an issue with the shell. On the other hand, if your C program produces different output, it's an issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Bash in your console. Your issue is not related to C, rather than how does **Bash** process strings. According to `man`:

> Enclosing  characters  in double quotes preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $, `, \,  and, when  history  expansion  is  enabled,  !.  When the shell is in posix mode, the ! has no special meaning within  double  quotes,  even  when history  expansion  is  enabled.   The characters $ and ` retain their special meaning within double quotes.  **The backslash retains its  special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: $, `, ", \, or newline.**  A double quote may  be  quoted  within  double quotes  by  preceding it with a backslash.  If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an !   appearing  in  double  quotes  is escaped  using  a  backslash.   The  backslash preceding the !  is not removed.

So in Bash both `"\a"` and `"\\a"` are treated the same as "\a". If you want to have four backslashes in double quotes you will need to write 8 of them. Try `echo "\\\\\\\\"`